# Search with generic data types in ASP MVC/Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Below is code I use in a WCF Service Reference I'm building using the Entity Framework. As you can see, right now I'm using the same code over and over again. Is there a syntax that will allow me to replace the entities with a generic type or another such method that would cut down on the amount of code being used?

```
        var aI = (from AgentIdentification s in _db.AgentIdentification
                  where s.SymetraNumber == sNum
                  select s);

        foreach (var record in aI)
        {
            _db.AgentIdentification.DeleteObject(record);
        }

        _db.SaveChanges();

        var aG = (from Agent s in _db.Agent
                  where s.SymetraNumber == sNum
                  select s);

        foreach (var record in aG)
        {
            _db.Agent.DeleteObject(record);
        }

        _db.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you want.

```
PerformChanges<YourDbObject, AgentIdentification>(x => x.AgentIdentification, sNum, _db);
PerformChanges<YourDbObject, Agent>(x => x.Agent, sNum, _db);

private void PerformChanges<DbType,TCollection>(Func<DbType,DbSet<TCollection>> FetchDbSetLambda, int sNum, DbType your_db)
        {
            var aI = (from s in FetchDbSetLambda(your_db)
                      where s.SymetraNumber == sNum
                      select s);

            foreach (var record in aI)
                FetchDbSetLambda(your_db).DeleteObject(record);
        }
```

Comment: The 'FetchDbSetLambda' keyword seems to be causing an error. I get this message after doing mouse-over: 'Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type 'TCollection'. 'Where' not found.

Comment: My apologies, I had some errors in the method declaration.  The Func<> type for TCollection should have been in an DbSet(assuming we are using EntityFramework).  As well, the name of the int parameter was wrong.